# MySQL Editor Hangs on attempt to Launch

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have just downloaded the latest Community Installer (5.5.27) along with the MySQL WorkBench (5.2.41). I clicked `OK` on all default settings on setup.

When I try to "Open a connection to start querying" on the WorkBench home page and chose "Local Instance MySql 55", I keep getting stuck on a never-ending "Opening SQL Editor" screen (*"An SQL Editor instance for "Local Instance MySql 55" is opening and should be available in a moment"*)

Any idea on what could be wrong ?

**EDIT :** 
I am able to access it from command line and query it successfully. But still not from query editor.

Comment: Is the mysql service running? Have you tried the Local Administration from the Workbench?

Comment: yes it is running, and I can access Server Administration for local MySQL55 on the WorkBench

Comment: Then porblem lies with Workbench as you are able to query using command line client.

Comment: Yes please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what happened. I launched a command window, it worked. Then I retried, after clearing the password vault, and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks Mika, I tried your solution in workbench (5.2.41). It worked after I cleared the passwords in the vault (click `Manage Connections`) and restarted the WorkBench.

To clear passwords stored in the vault, I did the following:

1. Open MySQL WorkBench the you will see the home page
2. Click **Manage Connection** at bottom left corner.
3. In Manage DB Connections, click **Clear** button besides Store in Vault...
4. Close it and restart WorkBench.
5. Double click Local instance mysql in home page, now you db will popup.

Answer (score 1):

When the default "Local instance MySQL Router" was not working and clearing the password vault didn't resolve it, I ended up creating a new connection (same settings, credentials, etc...) and used the new connection instead. You can safely delete the original after you have determined the new connection is working for you.

[image: Setup New Connection]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's problem not solved with these solutions, if you open Services, for me there were two services MySQL (running) and MySQL80 (stopped). I stopped MySQL and started MySQL80 and solved my problem immediatelly.

Comment: thta is not enough, if the service mysql is on automatic ´, it will statrt the next time after reboot, so you have to disable it too. and chekc if mnysql8 is on automatic start

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic, i also tried clearing passwords in the vault and all. But my problem didn't solve.

I started the **MySQL installer** and from there I ran the **Reconfigure** option for **MySQL Server**

Follow these screen shots to bring your instance back online.

#### MySQL Installer (Initial Screen)

[image: MySQL Installer (Initial Screen)]
Select the **Reconfigure** option on the topmost entry for **MySQL Server**.

#### MySQL Installer | Type and Networking

[image: MySQL Installer | Type and Networking]
Nothing to change here. Click on **Next >**.

#### MySQL Installer | Accounts and Roles

[image: MySQL Installer | Accounts and Roles]
Add your password for the **root** account and click on **Check** button. When the password has been verified click on **Next >**.

#### MySQL Installer | Authentication Method

[image: MySQL Installer | Authentication Method]
Leave the recommended option. Click on **Next >**.

#### MySQL Installer | Windows Service

[image: MySQL Installer | Windows Service]
Nothing to change in this window. Click on **Next >**.

#### MySQL Installer | Apply Configuration

[image: MySQL Installer | Apply Configuration]
In the summary windows click on the **Execute** button. The changes are applied to the system.

#### MySQL Installer | Apply Configuration (Finished)

[image: MySQL Installer | Apply Configuration (Finished)]
In the summary window you will see everything with green tick marks if everything was applied correctly.

Do what I did and don't change any type of standard settings. Just follow the buttons/screens and that's it.

Now your MySQL Workbench will open without any issues.
[image: MySQL Workbench opens up]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem when I manually changed the password and after I closed that session, when I restart it again, it hangs on the same page.

The solution which worked for me :

1. Right click -> edit connection
2. Enter the new password -> Test connection
3. If it succeeds, click Store in Keychain and close
4. Now double click the local instance - got opened